# PHP login with sha256 don`t works

Tags: php

In my login, the encrypted password from the post and the encrypted password in the database are different.

**PW in database:**

```
9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd1
```

**PW from the POST:**

```
9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
```

Code:

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['username'];
$passwort = $_GET['passwort'];

$database = mysqli_connect("CENSORED", "CENSORED", "CENSORED") or die("Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden. Fehler: ".mysqli_error());
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$username);
$passwort = hash("sha256", $passwort);
$pwabfrage = "SELECT passwort FROM CENSORED.Spoja WHERE username='$username'";

$retval = mysqli_query($database,$pwabfrage);

if(! $retval ) {
die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$pwfromdb = $row['passwort'];
echo "PWFROMDB: ". "$pwfromdb". " $passwort";
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to use a better hash like [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the hash in database is shorter than the actual one. Maybe you have a character limit on the database row.

Comment: Yes that was it! :) THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

Comment: You can mark the answer as the correct one. So others no that it's answered.

Comment: Yes I know but I had to wait 5 minutes.